# Configure WiFi using Pi as a Access Point with a Configuration UI

Tags: wifi

I want to setup my RPi as a wireless access point by default, then let an end-user open some browser-based UI to enter their own Wireless SSID and password, which would then be used by the RPi to connect to the Internet. Something like:

1. RPi is configured as a wireless access point as a default
2. User connects their device to the wireless network RPi is broadcasting
3. User points their device browser to a pre-specified IP address or URL (?)
4. RPi serves a web page where the user can enter their WiFi network SSID and password
5. RPi writes the SSID and password to the wpa_supplicant.conf file
6. RPi reboots (?)
7. RPi is connects to the Internet over users WiFi

Anyone know of a good tutorial out there for this?

Comment: No! It is conceivable possible, but nowhere near as simple as you suggest. It is easier to just put a wpa_supplicant.conf file in the boot partition of a normal Raspbian

Comment: @Milliways pray tell where the complexity lies? End-users won't have access to the boot partition...